# Angular 2 HTTP post using HttpInterceptor, unable to send image through formData in HTTP post

Tags: angular, http, post, image-uploading, interceptor

I would like to show the code am using now, so that i can receive solution to my problem
The below code is for API to store image in a local project folder

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/UploadFileApi")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Postfiles()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var docfiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/locker/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                docfiles.Add(filePath);
            }
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now in angular2 am calling the above API by below code in typescript when i a event binding property in UI

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        this.service.fileUpload(formData)
            .then(result => {
                this.Message = "The Image Uploaded Successfully" + file.name;
        });           
    }
    else {
        this.Message = "Image Not Uploaded";
    }
}
```

from above code it is going to service call(below code) if i use HttpInterceptor concept in angular2 the localhost is attached to the URL, after the below code.

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

fileUpload(formData) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "multipart/form-data");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('/api/UploadFileApi', formData, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

But when the above Post method is being called it is going to  httpinterceptor.post method using backendconnection, as i am trying to use this HttpInterceptor Concept in my project. below is the code

```
post(url: string, formData: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    url = this.updateUrl(url, options);
    return super.post(url, formData, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}
```

//here the environment.origin4="http://localhost:3636" 
//the return url is http://localhost:3636/api/UploadFileApi

`private updateUrl(req: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {

return environment.origin4 + req;

    }`

```
private getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {

    if (options == null) {

        options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {

        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    return options;
}
```

So when the above API is getting called the formData is not passed when am using httpinterceptor concept. if i am not using httpinterceptor the image is passed through formData to the API as HttpContext and image being stored.

If i dont use the HttpInterceptor concept, my sevice call from angular2 to API is like, so it is working fine(look at the change in URL).

```
fileUpload(formData) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "multipart/form-data");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3636/api/UploadFileApi', formData, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

But i have to use HttpInterceptor concept and develop the functionality, i do not know why the post from httpinterceptor is not passing formData to API. What i have to do now using HttpInterceptor.Post call to API

Comment: Guys, i got the issue... it is in interceptor. Am appending the content-type as application.json again so when it is going to API the file was not able to recognize.

Comment: what did you change in post request?